# Turn off the LCD display automatically without letting the laptop sleep

Tags: display, power-management, backlight

I have learnt that modern LCD displays don't need screen savers like legacy CRT monitors. So I decided to not to install screen savers. Instead, I want the programs running while I am away, **without locking the laptop** and the **display should go off** where I expect to turn it back on with a key press, mouse movement or tap on touch pad. Is it possible? Then how?

**In short, I want to turn the back lights off automatically, without locking the laptop. **I don't want to close the lid****

Answer (score 1):

In `Preferences>Power`, you can set the computer to do nothing when the lid is closed.

You can also set a certain grace period that allows you to **automatically turn off the display.** The display will turn back on upon an input event.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Can you please explain it?

Comment: @NuwanThisara It's the same as @heynnema's. Why don't you set it to do `nothing` when you shut the lid? Then, just leave it plugged in with the lid shut and the display ***will be off***.

Comment: Actually I couldn't mention a point, I don't want to close the lid. I go away from the laptop for a while without shutting the lid, I want the display to go off after sometime. Sorry I didn't mention that, I'll edit the question

Comment: @NuwanThisara What's the issue with closing the lid?? I guess you could bind 2 keyboard keys that turn off+turn on the display, but if you're running programs in the foreground that refresh constantly, then the display won't turn off.

Comment: No issue with closing the lid, but I usually don't do that and don't want. 

Comment: @NuwanThisara Create a shortcut, or a key binding, to issue this command: `xset dpms force off`. Press the key or shortcut icon, and then if you issue any input your computer will turn back on.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings, Brightness & Lock, and set it like this:

[image]

And Power settings:

[image]

Comment: should I reboot after changing these?

Comment: Not required...

Comment: Here is my settings [image](http://telegra.ph/brightness-12-06) when I am inactive nothing happens.

Comment: Try setting your inactive time to something greater than 1 minute. Otherwise, you have some application/process consuming cpu time and the computer never thinks it's inactive. In `terminal`, type `top` to see your processes.

Comment: I increased it to 5 minutes and waited.. nothing happened.. :(

Comment: Then use the `top` command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49686/discussion-between-nuwan-thisara-and-heynnema).

Comment: This didn't help. What may be the reason?

Comment: There can be 1001 reasons. Try turning off all of your `Startup Applications` and closing all of your extra top panel indicators. There is no easy way to diagnose this.

Comment: sad news. Then I will give up this.I want my startup apps running..  :-(

Comment: No, just turn them off temporarily to see if they effect the problem. Reboot after you turn them off.